# SOLVED: S3 Object Lock with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Is ObjectLock with Cloudformation Templates possibly still not implemented or is there an error in this template?

I tried to apply the following stack:

```yaml
---
Resources:
 TestBucketBucketProd:
  Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
  Properties:
   BucketName: testbucket-prod
   VersioningConfiguration:
    Status: Enabled
   AccessControl: Private
   Tags:
    - Key: org 
     Value: prod
   PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
    BlockPublicAcls: true
    BlockPublicPolicy: true
    IgnorePublicAcls: true
    RestrictPublicBuckets: true
   ObjectLockConfiguration:
    ObjectLockEnabled: true
    Rule:
     DefaultRetention:
      Mode: GOVERNANCE
      Days: 2
Outputs:
 TestBucketBucketName:
  Value: !Ref TestBucketBucketProd
  Description: The name of the TestBucket S3 bucket.
```

Applying the stack leads to a failure in creation:
Object Lock configuration cannot be enabled on existing buckets (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 409; Error Code: InvalidBucketState; Request ID: 0AF2GTWV4W9P4X1C; S3

The bucket did not exist before applying the stack.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

With help from AWS support, I got the solution.
I'll write it here, because I don't think, it is quite intuitive.
You need to hand over "ObjectLockEnabled" twice.

```
   ObjectLockEnabled: true
   ObjectLockConfiguration:
     ObjectLockEnabled: "Enabled"
     Rule:
       DefaultRetention:
       Mode: "GOVERNANCE"
       Days: 2
```

ChatGPT helped me with a solution for the CLI:

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket zentrada-dev-testbucket \ 
 --region eu-central-1 \ 
 --create-bucket-configuration \ 
 LocationConstraint=eu-central-1 --object-lock-enabled-for-bucket 

aws s3api put-object-lock-configuration \ 
 --bucket zentrada--dev-testbucket --object-lock-configuration \ 
'{"ObjectLockEnabled":"Enabled","Rule":{"DefaultRetention":{"Mode":"GOVERNANCE","Days":1}}}'
```